# Using IEqualityComparer<T> to determine uniqueness

Tags: c#

I am using a HashSet. I want to ensure that I don't have duplicate values. However, I am able to do so at the present moment.

```
[Serializable()]
public class SafetyObsDS
{
    public int Count
    {
        get { return set.Count; }
    }

    HashSet<CompResults> set;

    public SafetyObsDS()
    {
        set = new HashSet<CompResults>(new CompareToComparer());
    }

    public bool Add(CompResults cr)
    {
        set.Remove(cr);
        return set.Add(cr);
    }

    public bool Remove(CompResults cr)
    {
        return set.Remove(cr);
    }

    [Serializable()]
    private class CompareToComparer : IEqualityComparer<CompResults> 
    {
        public CompareToComparer() {}

        public bool Equals(CompResults cr1, CompResults cr2) 
        {
            return (cr1.CompareTo(cr2) == 0);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(CompResults cr)
        {
            return (cr.SectionID);
        }
    }
}

[Serializable()]
public class CompResults : IComparable
{
    public int SectionID { get; set; }

    public ComResults(int sectID)
    {
        SectionID = sectID;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        return SectionID - (obj as CompResults).SectionID;
    }

}
```

I left the constructors and additional unnecessary code such as other fields out
When I perform the following operations, I receive undesired results:

```
Add(new CompResults(1));     Result: true
Add(new CompResults(1));     Result: true  <--- this is a dup and I don't want it to add
Remove(new CompResults(1));  Result: true
```

thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is that in your `Add()` code, you first remove the existing item, then add the new (duplicated) one.  This will always be successful since there aren't any duplicates which is why it returns `true`.  Remove the `Remove()` call and it will fix itself.